# How can I render object HTMLDivElement in my react component?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsx

I have this code(its part from a bigger class but the relevant parts are here)

what I try to do is to take an existing div('#qr') that has a QR code that we got from Third Party and make some changes if needed after some checks.

I got this error:

> invariant.js:42 Uncaught (in promise) Error: Objects are not valid as a React child (found: [object HTMLDivElement]). If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead or wrap the object using createFragment(object) from the React add-ons. Check the render method of...

I'm looking for a way to render object HTMLDivElement in my react class.

the relevant code looks like this:

```
getQrCode() {
    const qrCodeElem = document.querySelector('#qr');

    const uri =  encodeURI('some specific url');

    if (qrCodeElem && qrCodeElem.childNodes.length === 0) {
        return new QRCode(qrCodeElem, {
            text: uri
        });
    }

    return qrCodeElem;
}

render() {
    return (
        <div>
            <div id="qr"></div>
            {this.getQrCode()}
        </div>
    );
}
```

Comment: React expects a `React.Component`. You can use something like this `https://github.com/zpao/qrcode.react` or create your own Component. Is there a way to grab the generated image? If so, use that.

Answer (score 0):

We can not insert DOM elements directly , you can use `ref` attribute to get reference to the parent element and insert your node after `componentDidMount`

```
getQrCode() {
    const qrCodeElem = document.querySelector('#qr');

    const uri =  encodeURI('some specific url');

    if (qrCodeElem && qrCodeElem.childNodes.length === 0) {
        return new QRCode(qrCodeElem, {
            text: uri
        });
    }

    return qrCodeElem;
}

componentDidMount () {

  this.qrCodeContainer.appendChild(this.getQrCode());
}

render() {
    return (
        <div ref={node => this.qrCodeContainer = node}>
            <div id="qr"></div>
        </div>
    );
}
```

Comment: This [seems to work](https://codesandbox.io/s/5xzlrm61v4) but clearly breaks React patterns. A dirty fix at best, and not a proper solution I guess.

Comment: If you query for DOM elements , you already broke the pattern :) , write `QRCode` as a react component as an alternative

Comment: and to write `QRCode` as a react component , you need to use the same approach. you can not avoid it :) , thats how lot of react components are implemented. There is nothing dirty!, Its all Javascript!

Comment: It's "dirty" in the sense that you're using `appendChild()`, which means the element is completely removed from React's life cycle or control. Your answer should mention this, since it's supposed to be useful to other people, too.

Comment: @PrashanthPamidi -  i have some problem with ref here, when i try your solution i got this error: Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read property 'appendChild' of undefined

Comment: @ErezLieberman May be the `querySelector` did not match any elements

Answer (score -1):

Your function is returning multiple dom nodes. Wrap them with additional tag (div, span, ...) or use fragments:

```
<>{this.getQrCode()}</>
```

Comment: This is not the issue.